# Writing csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a project im working on im trying to move one table to another one in python I need it to read two files and write them to specific places in the sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv if this is possible. This is the code i have so far is

```
import csv
with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
         print ', '.join(row)
with open('sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    addwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    addwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What is your question? All you've done is shown some code.

Comment: im asking if there is a way to fix the writer part of this to where is will write the contents of the first file to the new one because as of right now it only writes out one row

Comment: What do you want to do? (1) copy `Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv` to `sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv`; overwrite (2) Append contents of  `Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv` to `sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv` (3) something else

Comment: @HatterX and is the last row of the 'Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv'? Looks like 'row' is being overwritten. Along with 'print' in 'for' loop, you need to have 'addwriter...'

Comment: @falsetru im wanting to append contents from one to the other

Comment: @HatterX, I updated the questioni to make it clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append you need to open the file with append mode (`a`). Otherwise, opening file with write mode (`w`) truncate the file.

Simply copying file content does not require you to use `csv` module. Simply use [`file.writelines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines)

```
with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'rb') as f1, \
     open('sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'ab') as f2:
    f2.writelines(f1)
```

Above code assumes the existing file `sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv` ends with newline. If that is not guaranteed, you need to check it; If there's any content, but the last line does not ends with you need to add one.

```
import os

need_newline = False
try:
    with open('sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(0, 2)
        if f.tell() > 0:
            f.seek(-1, 1)
            need_newline = f.read(1) != b'\n'
except IOError:
    pass

with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'rb') as f1, \
     open('sample_FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'ab') as f2:
    if need_newline:
        f2.write(os.linesep.encode())
    f2.writelines(f1)
```